# How do I show all my Twitter friends?

Tags: php, twitter

This script isn't working so good.

```
<?php
//include twitter class
require('classes/twitter.php');

$twitter = new Twitter('custToken', 'custSecret');

// set tokens
$twitter->setOAuthToken('blah blah');
$twitter->setOAuthTokenSecret('blah blah');

//$tweet = "This tweet was posted from a custom php script.";
//$twitter->statusesUpdate($tweet); // <-- this works!

$friends = $twitter->friendsList('tynamite');
foreach ($friends as $friend){
    print_r($friend);
    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

I want to display all my Twitter friends (everyone I follow) in a list.
The result I am getting is this.

Could anyone please help on this?

Comment: what is wrong with "the result you get"?

Comment: The link you posted tells that you reached the Twitter API limit. Can you expand your Q? Now it's working and everything looks find, you get an array of friends, if your problem is the limit, just create a a cache with the data and then recache every hour.

Comment: What is wrong, is that it doesn't show ALL my Twitter friends. I follow 438 people, but I don't see 438 results on the page.

Comment: Ok. You see 20 friends because you don't specify a cursor, Just have to walk using cursors and you'll get 20 each time.

Comment: Cursors? Nothing in the Twitter Developers site said anything about cursors, to my knowledge. What are cursors?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring & https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a cursor. You could use something like the code below (untested and just pseudo-code):

```
while($count == 20) {
 $friends = $twitter->friendsList('tynamite', $cursor);
 $count = count($friends);
 $cursor++;

 .. your code ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

twitter uses json to return its results. you need to parse the results returned and pull out the information you need. check this [blog](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP) out for an example of how to use php to parse json